# If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $a \in G$. Show that $H$ and $a^{-1}Ha$ are isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I feel like I did something wrong, because I never actually used $a \in G$.

*Proof*:
Define $\alpha: H \rightarrow a^{-1}Ha$ by $\alpha(h)=a^{-1}ha$

Let $x,y \in H$ then,

$\alpha(xy) = a^{-1}xya\\   =(a^{-1}xa)(a^{-1}ya)\\  =\alpha(x) \alpha(y)\\$

So this implies that $\alpha$ is a **homomorphism**.

**Injective**:
Let $x,y \in H$ such that $\alpha(x)= \alpha(y)$

Then $a^{-1}xa=a^{-1}ya$, multiply on left and right by $a$ and $a^{-1}$

$aa^{-1}xaa^{-1}=aa^-1yaa^{-1}$

$x=y$
This implies $\alpha$ is one-to-one.

**Surjective**:
Let $x \in a^{-1}Ha$. Then $x=a^{-1}ha$ for some $h \in H$.

$\alpha(h)=a^{-1}ha=x$

So $\alpha$ is onto.

Therefore, $H $ and $a^{-1}Ha$$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Looks good. You are using that $a\in G$, otherwise it wouldn’t make sense to multiply by $a$ and $a^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're unsure. You used $a$ $28$ times by my count.

Comment: @TheoBendit Im laughing, you're right! Thank you.

Comment: It means that it holds whatever $a \in G$